# variance decomposition in ANOVA with a significant interaction

Tags: anova, variance

I have a simple model like `y~a*b`, in which `a` and `b` are categorical variables. In an ANOVA, the interaction between `a*b` is significant. How would I partition/decompose the variance that is explained by each factor and additionally by the interaction?

PS.: I am actually unsure the question is sensible, as the interaction is significant.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The model was fit as:

```
m1<-lm(y~a*b)
summary(m1)
```

output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a * b)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    bn        3Q       Max 
-0.089947 -0.015513 -0.001174  0.014987  0.101011 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              -0.057883   0.009793  -5.911 7.72e-08 ***
aeF                      -0.178063   0.014228 -12.515  < 2e-16 ***
asN                      -0.010012   0.015991  -0.626  0.53300    
asR                       0.051663   0.018320   2.820  0.00604 ** 
asT                       0.026106   0.015261   1.711  0.09097 .  
asR                       0.049636   0.016961   2.926  0.00445 ** 
agF                      -0.099435   0.020385  -4.878 5.27e-06 ***
amF                      -0.085776   0.015991  -5.364 7.54e-07 ***
bcat2                     0.002509   0.015991   0.157  0.87574    
aeF:bcat2                 0.152028   0.022850   6.653 3.12e-09 ***
asN:bcat2                -0.039467   0.023987  -1.645  0.10378    
asR:bcat2                -0.008895   0.026216  -0.339  0.73527    
asT:bcat2                -0.060813   0.023506  -2.587  0.01147 *  
asR:bcat2                -0.004785   0.024644  -0.194  0.84655    
agF:bcat2                 0.082009   0.027115   3.025  0.00334 ** 
amF:bcat2                 0.039959   0.023987   1.666  0.09961 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03097 on 81 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.835, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8045 
F-statistic: 27.33 on 15 and 81 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: hi @subhashc.davar, thanks for your reply. I have added the ANOVA output as an edit to the question.

Comment: Try `summary.aov(m1)` is that what you want? You can also do `m2 <- aov(y~a*b)` and then `summary(m2)`.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, thanks for your reply. Your suggestion will tell me whether the interaction and the two variables are significant. But what I need to know is how to partition the variance. If I had the two categorical variables without the interaction, it would be easy as I could just fit two models with each of the variables and get the R^2 for each of them. In my case, the interaction is significant, that is why I am unsure about what to do.

Comment: The output should also show the partitioned sums of squares and means squares for your factors and their interaction given your model, no? Maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, that was dumb of me. So the partitioned variance should be just dividing each of the categorical variables and the interaction by the total of the sum of squares right?

Comment: Yes if you sum up all sums of squares (incl. residual) you'll have the total sums of square (TSS). If you sum up all sums of squares (excl. residual), you'll have the model sums of squares (MSS). Now MSS/TSS should be your multiple R2. There are no dumb questions - only answers ;)

Comment: I will add this as an answer. Just give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following model:

```
m1 <- aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, npk)
summary.lm(m1)

Call:
aov(formula = yield ~ block + N * P + K, data = npk)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-6.058 -1.573  0.225  2.204  5.542 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   52.858      2.552  20.709  6.7e-12 ***
block2         3.425      2.796   1.225  0.24081    
block3         6.750      2.796   2.414  0.03005 *  
block4        -3.900      2.796  -1.395  0.18481    
block5        -3.500      2.796  -1.252  0.23117    
block6         2.325      2.796   0.832  0.41963    
N1             7.500      2.283   3.285  0.00542 ** 
P1             0.700      2.283   0.307  0.76365    
K1            -3.983      1.614  -2.468  0.02711 *  
N1:P1         -3.767      3.229  -1.167  0.26284    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.954 on 14 degrees of freedom
**Multiple R-squared:  0.7502**,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5896 
F-statistic: 4.672 on 9 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.005224
```

You can see the Multiple R-squared is 0.7502. Now by looking at the `summary(m1)` output you get all the partitioned variances (i.e. Sums of Squares):

```
> summary(m1)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
block        5  343.3   68.66   4.391 0.01295 * 
N            1  189.3  189.28  12.106 0.00368 **
P            1    8.4    8.40   0.537 0.47564   
K            1   95.2   95.20   6.089 0.02711 * 
N:P          1   21.3   21.28   1.361 0.26284   
Residuals   14  218.9   15.64                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

You can double check and calculate the multiple R-squared from the `summary.lm()` output above by doing:

```
> tss <- 343.3+189.3+8.4+95.2+21.3+218.9
> mss <- 343.3+189.3+8.4+95.2+21.3
> mss/tss
[1] 0.7502282
> 343.3/tss + 189.3/tss + 8.4/tss + 95.2/tss + 21.3/tss
[1] 0.7502282
```

Both calculations are identical and result in the Multiple R-squared of 0.7502. There is also an [adjusted R-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2), which takes into account the number of independent variables in your model.